# We saw a blank page at /checkout/* after applying SUPEE-10752 and compiling

Tags: supee-10752

We saw a blank page at /checkout/* after applying SUPEE-10752 and compiling

version: 1.9.1.0

Triggering conditions:applying SUPEE-10752 + enable compiler + login as a customer, then visit /checkout/*

Just to clarify: With deactivated compiler all things went well, with activated compiler we only could see a blank cart page when logged in without any log entries (even after activating all possible logs and developer mode).

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Comment: disable compiler

Comment: Hello @jun, did you try my solution ? If have any issue, just let me know.

Comment: no, i commented getPasswordTimestamp

Comment: @Pawan I tried your solution and it is fixing it but got another issue that when I am Registering customer and placing order, it is redirecting success page to homepage.
Any fixes?

Answer (score 4):

I Have got same issue some times ago and found a work around [Here](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/152-magento-onlineshop-supee-10570-und-weisse-seite-bei-warenkorb)

You need to copy from:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
```

To

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php
```

Search function :

```
public function getPasswordTimestamp($customerId)
{
    /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
        ->load((int)$customerId);
    $passwordCreatedAt = $customer->getPasswordCreatedAt();

    return is_null($passwordCreatedAt) ? $customer->getCreatedAtTimestamp() : $passwordCreatedAt;
}
```

**Replace it with:**

```
public function getPasswordTimestamp($customerId)
{
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('customer_entity').' WHERE `entity_id` = '.$customerId; 
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

    $result=$results[0]; $result=$results[0]; 
    $date_created = Varien_Date::toTimestamp($result['created_at']); 
    return $date_created;
}
```

After that you need to `recompile` and `flush cache`:

**Note:** in [Blog](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/152-magento-onlineshop-supee-10570-und-weisse-seite-bei-warenkorb) , They explain due to patch, customer load is failed and we manually need to get `created_at` of current user.

Answer (score 1):

Still investing this but by enabling the `scream` option on xdebug, I was able to determine that the problem is the `Zend_Date` class is loaded twice when compilation is enabled and the `load` function is called on a customer, hence the error.

On the checkout pages specifically, it is included in the `__checkout.php` file and the `Zend_Date.php` file is also included.

The replacement code above, while it allows for compilation to proceed by not loading the customer model, does not account for the new `password_created_at` attribute created by this patch.

**Side Note:** The `Varien_Autoload` class has the suppression operator (`@`) which prevents errors from being logged or displayed(!!), hence the blank page/lack of logging.

`@include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: You are very professional,  tell me if have a good solution, thanks